# Problem med space in path in Proguard parameter call

Tags: proguard

When I am trying to this parameter to Proguard, it throws this exception:

java -Xms128M -Xmx256M -jar "../../../tools/proguard/proguard.jar" @game_specific.pro -libraryjars "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/rt.jar"
Error: Expecting class path separator ';' before 'Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/rt.jar in argument number 3

This is due to the space in the file name, I know that much. I have tried various work-arounds with " and ', but the only thing that works is when I use progra~1 in the path.
This is not a viable solution for me, since this command should be able to run on a lot of different computer with various paths to Java.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of convenience, ProGuard accepts arbitrarily grouped command-line arguments, using shell quotes, e.g.:

```
java -jar proguard.jar "-keep public class * { public <methods>; }"
```

The shell groups the arguments and gobbles the quotes. As a result, file names containing spaces have to be quoted once more, e.g. with different quotes:

```
java -jar proguard.jar "-injars 'some input.jar'"
```

This double-quoting problem doesn't exist for options in configuration files.

The issue is mentioned in the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filename).

Comment: Exactly what was wrong. The quotes around the file name did the trick.